For estimating weights in the Synthetic Control Method, what linear combination of the outcomes and symmetric matrix are used?
I am reading Synthetic Control Methods for Comparative Case Studies Paper, and on pg. 5 it states how to estimate Synthetic Control Weights. The following is a summary of the methods in the paper. I am quite confused on two points:

Why is there so much flexibility given over what the linear combinations over the pre-intervention outcomes can be? (i.e. can be the mean, can be equal to to the last outcome)
I always thought $X_1$ and $X_0$ were the covariates, but it seems it includes both covariates and pre-intervention outcomes. Why is that
In measuring the discrepancy, why is $V$ introduced? It seems completely out of left field to me, is this a technique from optimization theory?


Let $W$ be a $(J \times 1)$ vector of positive weights summing to one:
$$W = (w_2, \ldots, w_{J+1})^{\top}, \quad w_2 + \cdots + w_{J+1} =
> 1.$$
Each value of $W$ represents a synthetic control as a weighted average
of the available control regions. The outcome of interest is observed
over $T$ periods for the treated ($Y_{1t}$) and control ($Y_{jt}$)
regions, where $j = 2, \ldots, J + 1$.
Let the $(T_0 \times 1)$ vector $K = (k_1, \ldots, k_{T_0})^{\top}$
define a linear combination of preintervention outcomes:
$$\bar{Y}_{K_i} = \sum_{s=1}^{T_0} k_s Y_{is}.$$
Consider $M$ such linear combinations, $K_1, \ldots, K_M$. Let:
$$X_1 = (Z_1^{\top}, \bar{Y}_{K_1}^{1}, \ldots,\bar{Y}_{K_M}^{1})^{\top},$$
a $(k \times 1)$ vector of preintervention characteristics for the
treated region, where $k = r + M$. Similarly, $X_0$ is a $(k \times J)$ matrix containing the same variables for control regions, with the
$j$-th column as:
$$(Z_j^{\top}, \bar{Y}_{K_1}^{j}, \ldots, \bar{Y}_{K_M}^{j})^{\top}.$$
where $Z_i$ is the observed covariate vector.
The vector $W^{\ast}$ minimizes the distance between $X_1$ and $X_0
> W$, using
$$\| X_1 - X_0 W \|_V = \sqrt{(X_1 - X_0 W)^{\top} V (X_1 - X_0 W)},$$
where $V$ is a symmetric and positive semidefinite matrix. An optimal vhoice of $V$
assigns weights to linear combinations of the variables in $X_0$ and $X_1$ to minimize
the MSE of the synthetic control estimator.


Q.1) Such flexibility is designed to account for all possible criteria for valid comparability while having some computational efficiency and interpretability. The goal is to construct a synthetic control unit such that the treated unit is conditionally exchangeable with it in the absence of treatment. Essentially, one is creating a counterfactual for the treated unit, and its identification (in nonexperimental settings) is derived from graphical or structural criteria. For example, consider the following structures, where $D$ represents (selection into) treatment:

The Markovian structure: All the necessary information about pre-intervention outcomes is captured by the last outcome alone. Therefore, the synthetic control and the treated unit should be exchangeable in the absence of treatment conditional on $\{Z, Y_{T_0}\}$. This means that vector $K$ would be $(k_1=\cdots=k_{T_0-1}=0, k_{T_0}=1)$. For example, consider the following structure and note that, to identify the causal effect of $D$ on each $Y_{\tau}$, with $\tau > T_0$, it is sufficient to control for $Z$ and $Y_{T_0}$.



The dense structure: All the information on pre-intervention outcomes is required, so the synthetic control and the treated unit would be exchangeable in the absence of treatment conditional on
$\{Z, Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_{T_0}\}$. This results in $T_0$ vectors, the vector-basis of $\mathbb{R}^{T_0}$; i.e., $K_1=(1,0,\cdots,0)$, $K_2=(0,1,\cdots,0)$, $\cdots$, $K_{T_0}=(0,0,\cdots,1)$. In the following structure, to identify  the causal effect of $D$ on each $Y_{\tau}$, with $\tau > T_0$, it is necessary to control for $Z$ and all $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_{T_0}$.



Full average: All the necessary information about pre-intervention outcomes is captured by the average, so the synthetic control and the treated unit should be exchangeable in the absence of treatment conditional on $\{Z, T_0^{-1} \sum_{s=1}^{T_0} Y_s\}$. Here, $(k_1 = \cdots = k_{T_0-1} = k_{T_0} = 1/T_0)$. This approach would also be justified from the dense structure, as it involves all the pre-intervention outcomes, but it is more constrained, as it reduces the dimension of such information from $T_0$ to 1.

Cumulative average: All the necessary information about pre-intervention outcomes is captured by the cumulative averages. Thus, the synthetic control and the treated unit should be exchangeable in the absence of treatment conditional on $\{Z, Y_{T_0}, (Y_{T_0} + Y_{T_0-1})/2, (Y_{T_0} + Y_{T_0-1} + Y_{T_0-2})/3,\cdots, T_0^{-1}\sum_{s=1}^{T_0}Y_s\}$. Here, vectors $K$ would be $K_1 = (0,0,\cdots,0,1)$, $K_2 = (0,0,\cdots,1/2,1/2)$, and so on. This approach would also be justified by the dense structure, and it would be equivalent, under a linear model for each $Y_{\tau}$, with $\tau > T_0$, to the one coming from using the vector-basis for $\mathbb{R}^{T_0}$. This is because the linear span of the $K$ vectors is the same for both approaches. They might lead to different estimates in a nonlinear model. Besides, the cumulative average might be easier to interpret in a time series models and other contexts. In practice, to gain some computational efficiency, a smaller number of $K$ vectors can be used, i.e, $K_1,K_2,\cdots,K_q$ with $q<T_0$.


Therefore, the formulation in terms of linear combinations of pre-intervention outcomes is sufficiently flexible to encompass various criteria for comparability, including those related to graphical conditions for conditional exchangeability (ranging from the Markovian to the dense cases), as well as other criteria for comparability, computational efficiency, and interpretability.
Q.2) Under the assumption of no anticipation effect, all pre-intervention outcomes effectively act as covariates. In certain settings, they may offer more valuable information for modeling post-intervention outcomes than other covariates. For example, if $Y$ follows a conditional autoregressive model (CAR) with low volatility, then it depends strongly on some lagged values. Additionally, as mentioned in the response to Q.1), pre-intervention outcomes might be necessary to ensure conditional exchangeability in certain causal structures. For instance, in the second graph above, all pre-intervention outcomes act as confounders between $D$ and each post-intervention outcome, and therefore they must be controlled for.
Q.3) Once again, the formulation using matrix $V$ aims to provide the most general framework, allowing the researcher to choose a specific case based on the application. For instance, if $V$ is set to the identity matrix, the optimal $W^*$ would minimize the Euclidean distance $||X_1-X_0W||$. However, consider a dataset where one variable is measured in millions of dollars, another in cents, another in meters, and another in square meters, all with vastly different variances. Some variables might be highly correlated while others are not. In such a heterogeneous and complex dataset, using the Euclidean distance might result in a poorly-behaved $W^*$, for instance: too sensitive to outliers. An alternative approach is to use the Mahalanobis distance, which involves setting $V$ to the inverse of the covariance matrix of all variables in $X$ (considering both treated and untreated units), i.e., $V=\operatorname{Cov}(X)^{-1}$. This transformation rescales the axes to have unit variance, making the Mahalanobis distance equivalent to the standard Euclidean distance in the transformed space. The Mahalanobis distance offers several advantages: it is unitless, scale-invariant, and accounts for the correlations within the dataset. The paper also discusses other options for $V$ and their respective advantages.
